# Why once deployed on Heroku I receive an "error compiling CSS assets"?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sass, asset-pipeline

I saw similar questions but the error clause is a bit different, an I think is something about the assets pipeline.

The error:

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
    (in app/app/assets/stylesheets/entypo.css)

    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:32 in 'resolver'
```

What I did was to implement a Boostrap theme in the vendor directory, so is already included in the assets pipeline.
The entypo.css is the first file required by the theme main file called style.css , which is placed in

```
   app/assets/stylesheets/
```

while entypo.css is placed in:

```
   vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

I'm not sure that the error resides here, because locally everything works just fine, the issue comes when I deploy on Heroku, because for some reason the compiler seeks for the css to compile in

```
  app/app/assets/stylesheets/entypo.css
```

Any clue?

Comment: Ok I've made some progress.
For some reason the rake assets:precompile does not run on my machine. When I try to deploy on Heroku, Heroku detects a manifest.yml and does not precompile css like bootstrap.min.css, when in fact I'd need Heroku to precompile them.


The catch is that even tough the manifest.yml doesn't exists in my /public/ folder, Heroku keeps on detecting it.

Comment: manifest.yml is in public/assets. If Heroku detects it, it does not precompile assets. Sounds like you have public/assets/manifest.yml in your git repo

Comment: Solved, simply there was a min.CSS with some errors, which was requiring others css.

It has been sufficient to check the Heroku logs, spot the errors in the CSS, precompile the assets and deploy.

Comment: @e4r If you have answered your own question, you may want to add it as an answer to this question and accept it for future reference.